# Use field in csv as _id in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, csv, header, database

Is there any way to use a field in a csv file as the `_id`-field in `mongo`, without renaming that field to `_id`? Example, using mongoimport:

```
regnr, lastname, firstname
01, Smith, John
```

and then have `regnr` as the primary -_id?

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? In shell you just insert your own `_id` with the value of `regnr`

Comment: I'm trying to do this using mongoimport.

Comment: What's the problem with renaming? Or duplicating the column?

Comment: Also, you're confusing `_id` and `ObjectId`. Former is the name of primary key, latter is just a data type (that's used by default for `_id` field). `"01"` is not a valid value for an `ObjectId`.

Comment: That is true. This is my first encounter with mongo and everything is kind of new to me.

Comment: You cant override the '_id' field in a mongo document. If you don't supply an appropiate _id field, it will generate one for you.